# Set up default radio button h:selectOneRadio on JSF

Tags: jsf, selectoneradio

I have this code

```
<h:selectOneRadio  value="#{MyBean.valueAttr}" >
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Button1"/>
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Button2" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Button3" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to set up the  `Button3` as the chosen button (default) initially.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add `itemValue` attribute to your `f:selectItem` and set default value of `#{MyBean.valueAttr}` in your bean